# How to continuously check Pin status in infinite while loop

Tags: gpio, python-3, raspberry-pi-desktop

I am working with Raspberry Pi 4 and using python for some project.

The sample code is as below:

```
while True:
     if( GPIO.input(a)==GPIO.LOW):
          if __name == '__main__':
             try:
               #Running multiple threads
             except KeyboardIntrupt:
                pi.stop()
     if( GPIO.input(b)==GPIO.LOW):
          if __name == '__main__':
             try:
               #Running multiple threads
             except KeyboardIntrupt:
                pi.stop()
     if( GPIO.input(c)==GPIO.LOW):
          if __name == '__main__':
             try:
               #Running  multiple threads
             except KeyboardIntrupt:
                pi.stop()
```

The above written code is just an example of what am doing in my real code.

So in while loop their are multiple if else that runs based on PIN status (GPIO pin LOW). Problem is that once one pin gets low it enters in one IF but never comes out of it even after pin gets high and ignores all other if cases.

Is their any way to execute these if conditions continuously based on PIN status.

- Only one pin gets LOW at one time. Multiple pins does not have Low
  state

Comment: Have you tried using interrupt-on-change callbacks for the pins instead of polling them in the loop? For example, using [edges][https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/api_pins.html#gpiozero.Pin.edges] and [when_changed][https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/api_pins.html#gpiozero.Pin.when_changed] in gpiozero.

Comment: Not Pi specific.  This appears to be a general how do I program question.

Comment: @joan  can you suggest solution to this program then?. I am stuck badly at this point

Comment: WHY? Learn to program! I suggest `Button` `when_pressed` https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html#regular-classes

Comment: @Milliways thanks for valuable suggestion

Comment: @RogerJones thanx alot, issue solved with add_event_detect ....